# How NOT to send back a response to ajax post call in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, redirect

I have an ajax post call and I want to just send the form values without waiting for a response to come. I want to redirect from my express app and not form my client side. server-side:

```
router.post("/", (req, res)=>{ 
     res.status(200).send(`signup/confirm-email?v=${req.body.email}`);
     // i want to be able to rediect with res.redirect("signup/confirm-email?v=${req.body.email}")
     }; 
});
```

client-side:

```
    $.post('/signup', $('#signup-form-container form').serialize())
 .done(lnk=>{
       window.location.replace(`${window.location}${lnk}`); })
 .fail(function(xhr){ //handle errors };
```

The code above works, it sends a response to ajax and then i redirect from client side.
I want to redirect from server-side.
I tried to redirect from my express app using res.redirect() but it doesn't work without logging any errors to the console and in the network tab in the dev tool, it shows that the request type is xhr. If there isn't a solution to this problem, than is there a way to hide the query in the route recieved. I don't want `v=${req.body.email}` to be displayed in the url bar. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using jQuery, it will almost always lead to bad practices and unmaintainable code.

You should use plain Javascript or React if you need a framework (which is mainly if you need to work on a big project, but may not be suited for total JS beginner). My solution here is in plain Javascript.

As a replacement for the jQuery request util (`$.post()`, etc ...), browsers have a very good HTTP request API named [fetch (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). I use it in this solution.

If you don't want to show the `email` param in the URL, you can set it in the `localStorage`.

You cannot redirect directly from Express for a `POST` method. Only if you were trying to `GET` a page, Express could redirect to another `GET` (and so change the URL in your browser).

The only solution to your need is to use the `window.location` after receiving the response from your `/signup` endpoint.

Server-side:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  const form = req.body.form
  // your registration code here
  // ...
  res.json({
    success: true,
    email: form.email
  })
})
```

Client-side:
`signup.js`

```
const form = {
  email: document.getElementById('email').value
  // add other fields you need
}

fetch('/signup', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ form })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    // Set the localStorage item so you can get it back
    // in the JS script of /signup/confirm-email
    localStorage.setItem('email', res.email)

    // Redirect to the confirm email page
    window.location = '/signup/confirm-email'
  })
```

Client-side:
`confirmEmail.js`

```
const email = localStorage.getItem('email')
if (!email) window.location = '/signup'

// proceed with your code
```

[Code for this answer](https://github.com/SherloxFR/StackOverflow-Answers-Code/tree/master/answers/express-redirect-fetch)

Comment: This totally what i need. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, I have a Discord server where we help each others, don't hesitate joining it :) https://discord.gg/C2bVzgb

Comment: @SherloxFR you are a little confused. You recommend avoid using AJAX and use Fetch API instead. AJAX stands stands for Asynchronous JavaScript. So Fetch is a modern way to perform AJAX requests.

Comment: Yes mb, I was just getting out of bed XD I meant avoid using the jQuery HTTP client ^^ Thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: Please can you tell me what is wrong with jquery, Like jquery vs fetch

Comment: @EyePatch as stated in my answer, jQuery "will almost always lead to bad practices and unmaintainable code". In a more general statement, I would say that using a Javascript library without fully understanding deeply Javascript is a mistake. But jQuery is worse than just that, because it is poorly optimized ([Pure Javascript is up to 10x faster](https://medium.com/@trombino.marco/you-might-not-need-jquery-a-2018-performance-case-study-aa6531d0b0c3)), and is a true "gaz factory", packing a lot of things you will _never_ need.

Comment: Yeah, now I'm trying to convert my jquery to fetch. Thanks

Comment: Erratum: `using a Javascript library without fully understanding deeply Javascript is a mistake.` I meant `using a framework without a good understanding of the underlying language is a mistake.` . jQuery is considered a library, but it is also a framework in the sense it abstracts a lot of the Javascript API from you.

Answer (score 1):

The point of Ajax is that the request is made by JavaScript and the response is handled by JavaScript.

If you return a redirect response, then JavaScript will follow the redirect, make a new request, and handle the response to that.

If you don't want to handle the response with JavaScript: **Don't use Ajax**. Use a regular form submission instead.

Comment: is there a way to hide the query in the url adress bar?

Comment: Don't put it there in the first place. (It isn't something you should worry about those, it is data sent from the browser, so the user already has access to it).

Comment: Thank you. But can i pass that kind of data to a cookie so the user can't see it?

Comment: You can't. Cookies are stored by the browser and sent from the browser to the server with every request. The browser belongs to the user and is completely under their control. They can inspect and modify the cookies it stores and sends at will.

Comment: @EyePatch Yes there is: `<form method="post">...` will make an HTTP request without showing the request parameters in the address bar. zero javascript necessary. This is what Quentin means by don't use ajax. Just use HTML forms properly. Google "mdn form" to learn more

Comment: @slebetman — The user can still see it. It's in the form. It's in the Network tab of the browser developer tools. It isn't in the URL, but it isn't hidden.

Comment: @Quentin the OP do not wants to totally hide the form content from the user, as the user typed this content. He just wants to avoid having an URL with params like `?x=bla&y=bla`.

Comment: @Quentin The OP never asked to hide the data form the user. Just to hide it from the url address bar